# swift userNotificationCenter check Identifier

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I have just confirmed that if the `UNUserNotificationCenter` was turned on, the `userNotificationCenter` function would also be turned on.

So I want to check the Identifier in the `userNotificationCenter` function and change the notification according to the Identifier.

1.How to check the Identifier in the `UNUserNotificationCenter` function

2.How to change the alarm content (for example, title ...) in the `UNUserNotificationCenter` function

What are some ways?

Comment: Do you want to check the identifier of the notification that was received?